# stopping content from 'jumping' when navbar fixes to top of screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a site that utilizes the Bootstrap 3 navbar. It is positioned 280px below a block div and sticks to the top of the page when scrolled to that point

HTML  ( in < head > tags )

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
  var s = $("#nav");
  var pos = s.position();                    
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    var windowpos = $(window).scrollTop();
    if (windowpos >= pos.top) {
        s.addClass("stick");
    } else {
        s.removeClass("stick"); 
    }
  });
});
```

HTML

```
<div id="nav">
  <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static">
     <!-- .btn-navbar is used as the toggle for collapsed navbar content -->

...
```

CSS

```
header {
  height:280px;
}

.stick {
  position:fixed;
  top:0px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

It sticks to the page when it's scrolled to the way it's supposed to. BUT when the 'nav' div gets the position:fixed attribute applied, it no longer is in the content flow and the content 'jumps' up the same height as the height of the nav.

How can I keep the content from jumping?

Comment: You can create a container around your element. Apply same to the container. Then you can fix your header to top but its parent element will occupy the same height

Comment: I am a it confused as to what you mean

Comment: I added it as an answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create a wrapping element around your header. Apply same height to the wrapper.
Now if you make your header fixed, the wrapper element will still be there, occupying the same height

here's an example

```js
 $(document).ready(function() {
  var s = $("#nav");
  var pos = s.position();                    
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    var windowpos = $(window).scrollTop();
    if (windowpos >= pos.top) {
        s.addClass("stick");
    } else {
        s.removeClass("stick"); 
    }
  });
});
```

```css
body {margin:0}

#nav, .nav-wrapper {
  height:100px;
    background: gray;
}

.stick {
  position:fixed;
  top:0px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Content content content<br>
Content content content<br>
Content content content<br>
Content content content<br>
Content content content<br>
Content content content<br>

<div class="nav-wrapper">
    <div id="nav">
        <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static">Header</div>
    </div>
</div>

Content content content<br>
Content content content<br>
Content content content<br>
Content content content<br>
Content content content<br>
Content content content<br>
Content content content<br>
Content content content<br>
Content content content<br>
Content content content<br>
Content content content<br>
Content content content<br>
Content content content<br>
Content content content<br>
Content content content<br>
Content content content<br>
Content content content<br>
Content content content<br>
Content content content<br>
Content content content<br>
Content content content<br>
Content content content<br>
Content content content<br>
Content content content<br>
Content content content<br>
Content content content<br>
Content content content<br>
Content content content<br>
Content content content<br>
Content content content<br>
Content content content<br>
Content content content<br>
Content content content<br>
Content content content<br>
Content content content<br>
Content content content<br>
Content content content<br>
Content content content<br>
Content content content<br>
Content content content<br>
Content content content<br>
Content content content<br>
Content content content<br>
Content content content<br>
Content content content<br>
Content content content<br>
Content content content<br>
Content content content<br>
Content content content<br>
Content content content<br>
Content content content<br>
Content content content<br>
Content content content<br>
Content content content<br>
Content content content<br>
Content content content<br>
Content content content<br>
Content content content<br>
Content content content<br>
Content content content<br>
Content content content<br>
Content content content<br>
Content content content<br>
Content content content<br>
Content content content<br>
Content content content<br>
Content content content<br>
Content content content<br>
Content content content<br>
Content content content<br>
Content content content<br>
Content content content<br>
Content content content<br>
Content content content<br>
Content content content<br>
Content content content<br>
Content content content<br>
Content content content<br>
Content content content<br>
Content content content<br>
Content content content<br>
Content content content<br>
Content content content<br>
Content content content<br>
```

Comment: sorry, just noticed there is a small jump still. not as big, not sure if this is a browser issue or not.

Comment: it's more a jump to the side, when it goes to fixed, it realigns (lessens padding etc)

Answer (score 1):

Don't create a custom class like `sticky` for it use `navbar-fixed-top` class like,

```
if (windowpos >= pos.top) {
    s.addClass("navbar-fixed-top");
} else {
    s.removeClass("navbar-fixed-top"); 
}
```

[Refer](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_navbar.htm)

Comment: will that remain at the bottom of the 'header' div when it's scrolled to the top, and will it go back to its position if the user scrolls back up?

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue too recently. I solved it by putting a position:absolute div behind my nav and using that as my scroll point reference for the addClass. Honestly I'm not quite sure why it worked, but it did!